# Can i get a missing social layer for Sharepoint intranets e.g A third party

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, social

Hi there I came across this article

http://www.headshift.com/our-blog/2011/10/19/can-ibm-connections-provide-the-missing-social-layer-for-sharepoint-intranets/

To prove that Sharepoint can deliver such environment.
Is there a 3rd party or any ideas how to get close to this?